# How to join two huge dataset in Optimal way in Scala Spark

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a very huge dataset on which I need to perform a join in order to enrich it with additional columns.
Dataset A contains the structure:-
`origin|destination|segment1_origin|segment2_origin|segment3_origin|segment4_origin|segment5_origin|segment6_origin|segment1_destination|segment2_destination|segment3_destination|segment4_destination|segment5_destination|segment6_destination`

and contains around 5 billion rows

Dataset B contains the structure:-
`origin|destination|stops|route`

The dataset B actually holds information about every segment in dataset A and is almost 6 times the size of dataset A

In order to enrich the stop and route details what I'm doing right now is:-

```
for (x <- 1 to 6){
    DatasetB.withColumnRenamed("stops", s"segment${x}_stops").withColumnRenamed("route", s"segment${x}_route")
    DatasetA.join(DatasetB, (col(s"segment${x}departure") === col("origin"))
            && (col(s"segment${x}Arrival") === col("destination")), "left").drop("origin", "destination")
}
```

And this solution is working fine. But my worry point is that I'm joining it 6 times. I was just curious to know if there is any way to make this optimized? This is causing skewness and the job gets slow at later stages.

Is there a way in Scala/Spark dataframe to write this in a better way?

Answer (score 1):

you can do `spark.sql` join with `or` condition so that you dont need to loop them.
Also if your data is skewed and taking time on few partitions then you can try `salting` technique, which will increase size of data but joins wont be stuck for longer.